# How to correctly reference hosting root?

Tags: php, filesystems

Say I have a "test.db" file under www.myhosting.com/data/test.db.
I need to reference this file from www.myhosting.com/inc/functions.php

What would be the proper way to reference the file?

```
$filename = '../data/test.db';
```

is not appropiate because www.myhosting.com/index.php would try to go to a non existant parent dir ../data

Answer (score 1):

Create (if you still doesn't have one) `config.php` file where you define **absolute** path to your root and include it in every your script. After that - use that constant to assemble path.

Ie:

```
$filename = ROOT_PATH . '/data/test.db';
```

Comment: An easy way to do this which still allows you to move things around without having to edit your config is `define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));` if your config is in the root.  You can then move to a subdirectory without breaking things.

Comment: so if i understood correcly, i need to create config.php under the root and in this file put define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__)); then in inc/functions.php put $filename = ROOT_PATH . '/data/test.db'; ?

Comment: @El Yobo: yep. I just gave the main hint about how to solve the issue. I still believe, that not-ready-to-use answer is better, because it allows user to think himself ;-)

Comment: @zafrada: probably now I will be a jerk, but why did not you try first? ;-) Yes, SO is great to get answer to any question, but **every** developer should be able to do experiments before asking obvious questions.

Comment: @zerkms: i did try it first and it did not work, thats why im asking. but i think i figured it out, config.php must be the first require() for this to work. however now im getting session errors for swapping the requires :)

Comment: @zafrada: "session errors for swapping the requires" -- ?!?!??

Comment: If you are using >= PHP 5.3, you can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)` :)

Comment: @zerkms: nevermind, i had a debuggin echo before session_start(); . ok i almost got it working, however im having trouble calling this config.php from inc/functions.php . include '../config.php'; is giving me Warning: include(../config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory . the file obviously exists

Comment: @zafrada: well, php said it is not.

Answer (score 1):

First way:

```
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/data/test.db';
```

Second:

```
$filename = getcwd() . '../data/test.db';
```